# Pass URL parameters to Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, url

I have the following code in one of my templates.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var val1 = 10;
        var val2 = 20;
    </script>
    <a href="/generate/">Generate</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish to use the values val1 and val2 in the `generate` function in the views.py file. It would be something like this.

```
def generate(request):
    # do something with val1 and val2
```

I am lost as to how I can pass these values to the function. What is the best practice for this, should I try to retrieve the information through URL parameters? Or perhaps I should just remove the Javascript and do everything in Python directly in the `generate()` function?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parameters using GET:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/generate/?val1=10&val2=20">Generate</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you can access them in view using request attribute:

```
def generate(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        val1 = request.GET.get('val1')
        val2 = request.GET.get('val2')
        #futher code
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#

Comment: I used this as it seems simpler and cleaner than using a form. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply HTTP methods such as GET or POST.

use this code in view template (example - `index.html`):

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/generate">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="number" name="val1" value="10">
        <input type="number" name="val2" value="20">
        <input type="submit" value="generate">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and use this code in `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request))

def generate(request):
    val1 = request.POST.get('val1', 0)
    val2 = request.POST.get('val2', 0)
    sum = val1 + val2

    return HttpResponse(str(sum))
```

This link is helpful for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/